# Focus listener for a label

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a grid with labels and I need to do an action when the label is clicked.

Do you know how can I achieve that? I prefer to use a label listener rather than clickable layout. I don't want to use buttons looking like plain text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Vaadin Labels don't have any click listeners  => you can't directly listen for clicks on Vaadin labels (at least not without descending down into javascript on the client).

In short : if you want to know when a component (and that component doesn't support the ClickListener), clickable layouts are the canonical approach.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no way for `com.vaadin.ui.Label` and for the `com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickListener` you have to use a flat Button.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to achieve this:

```
final Label label= new Label("My clickable Label");
        myForm.addComponent(label);
        myForm.addLayoutClickListener(new LayoutClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void layoutClick(LayoutClickEvent event) {
                // capture click and do whatever you'd like to do
                if (event.getClickedComponent() != null) {
                    if (event.getClickedComponent().equals(label)) {
                        System.out.println("clicked!");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```